# WrongClassException switching from eclipselink to Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, exception, jpa, limit

I had a working code written in pure JPA and running on Glassfish v3.0.1 (eclipselink)
I decided to switch persistence provider to hbernate 3.5.1-final and I'm experiencing exceptions in one query that had worked before.
All other queries( named queries) work fine. Could someone tell me what is wrong with the one below? 
I can't make it a named query because I need to sort the job by different parameters.

Why are the collections inside Job class not being queried?
Thanks for any help

javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.WrongClassException: Object with id: 16 was not of the specified subclass: mypackage.Job (Discriminator: )

Hibernate:

select job0_.id as id7_, job0_.version as version7_,
job0_.created as creat
ed7_, job0_.error_msg as error5_7_, 
job0_.priority as priority7_, 
job0_.retries as retries7_, 
job0_.status as status7_, 
job0_.subject as subject7_, 
job0_.user_id as user10_7_, job0_.DTYPE as DTYPE7_ from test_job job0_
where job0_.user_id=? order by job0_.created DESC limit ?

```
List foo;

   String qst = " SELECT e from Job e WHERE e.user = :user ";

   qst += " ORDER BY e." + orderBy;
   Query q = em.createQuery(qst); //TypedQuery +List
   q.setParameter("user", user);

   q.setMaxResults(length);
   q.setFirstResult(start);
   foo = q.getResultList();
```

Classes:

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries{}
Job extends BaseEntity{
...
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "job_address",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "address_id"))
    @NotNull
    protected Set FtpAddress> addresses;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "job_transmission",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "job_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "transmission_id"))
    protected Set Transmission> transmissions; 
}

@MappedSuperclass BaseEntity{
    int id
    int version ....
}
```

Comment: Does Job have any subclasses? - Because a Discriminator is used for such stuff.

Comment: No job doesn't have any subclasses. I have other classes that inherit from BaseEntity and persistence for them. Job has 2 transient properties the other classes do not. Does it make any difference?

Comment: BaseEntity is a MappedSuperclass, so hibernate should tread its subclasses as complete different.

Answer (score 0):

There is something completly wrong: the query:
`"SELECT e from Job e WHERE e.user = :user "`
would try to access a field "user" of class Job, but this class does not have such a field!